# Verify if a user is using English or latin characters and issue a warning if not

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm having a Django site, which is in English.

I know there are many other languages that use Latin besides English, but I have some 'pattern matching' issues in urls slugs with Cyrillic, Asian, Arab characters, and I want to avoid them.

I'm thinking to do a more generic clean, loop thru all the fields at once, instead of using clean_field for all fields in all forms.

Or maybe do it at the Model level.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered properly here, but I suggest you to look into writing your own validator.

Comment: You may use in-built python string function `isalnum()`

Comment: @Selcuck why is to broad ? I want to write my own validator, I just need to know how to identify them, definitely not letter by letter

Comment: ZdaR - isalnum() check if is alphanumeric, ok, but the input text can contain space, new line, other punctuations elements, so will flag everything

Comment: @JMo Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using regular expressions. I won't write it out for you, but if you match the input against something like

```
/.*[^A-Za-z\d\s\!@#\$].*/
```

with the rest of the legitimate special characters tacked on, you can see if it contains any characters outside of the range of alphabetics, digits, spaces, or other characters you list.